# Finding the Moved File?

Tags: c#, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

My questions is :
Let's say client using my program has file named 'temp' in Folder called 'FolderA' when he started my program he states the file's path then after sometime client decides to move this 'temp' file to somewhere else can be anywhere lets call this folder 'FolderB'. What I think to this point is after Client states the path of 'temp' file I will start monitoring directory with filesystemwatcher file is in and when delete trigger is fired (moving is seen as delete in filesystemwatcher), after that I will check every directory in disk for file with same name ( but this will take a will maybe in this little time file's name can be changed ? Let's say not changed for now) after I found the file with same name I will probably eliminate some of them with last access time but is there way to be sure about the files are being the same file ? Can I give a file some kind of signature without effecting the file ?

Comment: a) nothing can be fool-proof because after you built it, a new and improved version of fools will come along. b) when a user (re)moves a file form a location that should be backed up to another folder that is not part of the backup the backup contract is broken and void. c) as you can obeseve it you may log ot notify about the situation. And even offer to find the new location but you're  not obliged to and you should offer the user all you found to pick from. d) Normally the creation and/or modification dates should be stable, but there is no way to prevent effective sabotage..

Comment: I understood not a big suprise on that subject thanks for your answer what about marking giving signature or hiding a bytes inside the file without changing its content or way it gets progressed is there way that i can achieve this ?

Comment: Not knowing anything about the files I can't tell; in general this seems wrong. Anything you 'hide' in a file is a change to the content and unless you have full control about the file types you won't succeed. Think of a txt file or and image.. - You could create some hash, though; but again how easy and appropriate this may be will fully depend on the files, esp. on their sizes. - These hash/signature codes would have to be stored in a control file of your system, not in the files themselves.

Comment: I am going to use it for database file of firebird i thought about comparing hash of files but if file size is too big i can't know for sure if user changes file mid reading/hashing or something i am little lost on what to do

Comment: You can set read/write lock on the file to prevent the user from moving it, or at least while you compute the hash.